# Why does xlrd not get numbers above 99 to dict?

Tags: python, xlrd

I am new to python and i am trying to import from a xlsx sheet.

with module xldr but when it hit 100 it  goes wrong.

When i call a number above [99] i get a key error??

i now the dict can't read the nummer because it gives a '100':'100'instead of 
100:100 like al the other nummers do 99:99 ,

```
import xlrd

loc = ("c:/exel/loopline.xlsx")


workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

sheet.cell_value(0,0)

lusnummer = {}


for i in  range(3,140):


    cell_value_id2 = sheet.cell(i,1).value
    cell_value_lusnummer = sheet.cell(i,1).value
    lusnummer[cell_value_id2] = cell_value_lusnummer

print(lusnummer)
```

The output looks like the following:

> `, 99.0: 99.0, '100': '100',`

i like to now what i am doing wrong

Comment: I'm guessing that the formatting changes on your source sheet.  What happens when you do this loop? `for i in  range(3,140): print(i, sheet.cell(i,1).ctype, sheet.cell(i,1).value)`  I'm going to guess that the [ctype](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#xlrd.sheet.Cell) changes from 2 to 1 at that point (from XL_CELL_NUMBER to XL_CELL_TEXT).

Comment: first thank you for helping me,You are correct the ctype changes to 2 in the second collum.(99 2 97.0

101 2 99.0
102 1 100

Comment: i can not change the xlsx file so i have to change the unicode string to a float.

Comment: Change each `sheet.cell(i,1).value` to `float(sheet.cell(i,1).value)`.